# Zeroclipboard won't copy text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a problem with the Zeroclipboard system, I think I've made a mistake with the code.
It says that it has been copied, the only thing is that it hasn't been copied.

My code that I'm using.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a#copy-url').zclip({
            path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy: $('input#shorturl').text()
        });
    });
</script><a href="#" id="copy-url" />Klik hier om de URL automatisch te kopi&euml;ren</a>
<div id="shorten_link">
    <input type="text" name="url" id="shorturl" value="<?php echo $nwUrl; ?>" />
</div>
```

My console bug isn't giving me errors, so I don't know what the problem is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
$('input#shorturl').val()
```

instead

```
$('input#shorturl').text()
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me finally fixing this!